# USB ports detected but not active on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, ubuntu-drivers

Soon after installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my machine, 2 of my USB ports stopped working. One was immediate, while the other stopped after a few weeks of use. I have one USB port left at the moment to utilize.
Before resorting to reinstalling Ubuntu I wanted to check if I should change any possible configuration or execute commands to enable these USB ports. From the attached findings after running "dmesg | grep -i USB" I found that the USB ports are definitely identified.

I assume from this, the USB ports on the machine are fine. Is there anything with regards to driver packages that I should reinstall? It just seems odd that Ubuntu 18.04 can pick up on the hubs but when plugging anything in nothing appears to get picked up.
My system runs on a Dell XPS L502x with an i7 CPU. The eSATA USB port is the one that works while the 2 other USB 3.0 ports don't read anything. 
I'm just starting off in the world of Linux so I'm not as experienced as yet, so any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

[:~$ dmesg | grep -i USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAmu0.png)

Answer (score 0):

After installing multiple tools such as Hardinfo and Usbview investigating to no avail, I resorted to opening up my chassis and check the motherboard. It seems the USB 3.0 ports are broken(since they won't even power up a USB fan) leaving only the eSATA USB active. A motherboard replacement seems to be most likely if I'm planning to keep this machine going.